# Access items inside Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a Listview inside a Listview as you can see in my code. I am trying to collapse other categories when i open another. Is that possible? I have tried many things but I don't know how to access elements in other row...

```
<ListView x:Name="MainListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind menu}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MainCategories">
                <Grid Background="blue">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="test"
                               Text="{x:Bind CategoryName}"
                               Tapped="Category_TextBlock_Tapped"
                               FontSize="25" />
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                          Name="tittleGrid"
                          Background="Gray">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1,0,1,0"
                                Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="Price" />
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="QUantity"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ListView x:Name="SubListView"
                              Grid.Row="2"
                              Background="YellowGreen"
                              ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubMenuItems}">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                        Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding"
                                        Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                                        Value="Stretch" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Dishes">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{x:Bind dishName}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                            BorderThickness="1,0,1,0"
                                            Grid.Column="1">
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Text="{x:Bind dishPrice}" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{x:Bind dishPrice}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And here is the toggle-visibility method i have made and works fine for the one i am clicking but I want to collapse ALL the others when i expand the  one i click... I might have many mistakes in my code but I'm kinda new to UWP

```
private void Category_TextBlock_Tapped(Object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        CloseAllOthers();
        TextBlock categoryName = sender as TextBlock;
        Grid grid = (categoryName.Parent as Grid);
        ToggleVisibility(grid);

    }

    private void ToggleVisibility(Grid grid)
    {

        foreach (var gr in grid.Children)
        {
            if (gr.GetType() == grid.GetType() || gr.GetType() == MainListView.GetType())
            {
                if (gr.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    gr.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                    gr.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

[My result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNNVh.png)
[and the collapsed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27zmR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified example of what you want to do:

```
<ListView x:Name="menu" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MenuItems}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="onItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!-- Disable virtualization -->
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,10,0,10"/>
                <ListView x:Name="subMenu" ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubItems}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
                            <TextBlock Margin="20,5,0,5" Text="{x:Bind Text}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MenuItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new MenuItem()
        {
            Text = $"Menu item {i}",
            SubItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(j => new MenuItem()
            {
                Text = $"Sub item {i}.{j}",
            }).ToList(),
        }).ToList();
    }

    private void onItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in menu.Items)
        {
            var container = (ListViewItem)menu.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (container != null)
            {
                var subMenu = (container.ContentTemplateRoot as FrameworkElement)?.FindName("subMenu") as FrameworkElement;
                if (subMenu != null)
                {
                    subMenu.Visibility = e.ClickedItem == item ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach; I prefer more of a data-driven approach with bindings to control the visibility of the sub menus when the parent list item is selected, rather than accessing the view directly, but this is fine for simple scenarios.